# How do I get the replace to work as I intend in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to make it so that if the words from `$hello` are entered in `$words` they are replaced with **bonjour** but it does not work. How exactly would I go about doing this?

Code:

```
<?php
$words = $_POST['words'];
$hello = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo', 'sup');
$words = preg_replace('/\b'.$hello.'\b/i', '<span class="highlight">Bonjour</span>', $words);
echo $words;
?>
```

Comment: you trying to use `$hello` as a string, when it's an array! I suggest looking at `for` and `foreach` in the [php bible](http://php.net)

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an array to your pattern, it should be a string. You can implode this though, something like:

```
$words = 'Hello world';
$hello = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo', 'sup');
$words = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $hello).')\b/i', '<span class="highlight">Bonjour</span>', $words);
echo $words;
```

Comment: You should add brackets around value returned by `implode`.  Otherwise, it will work like `(\bhello)|(hi)|(yo)|(sup\b)` which is not what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to decide if you pass an array of patterns to `preg_replace`

```
$hello = array('/\bhello\b/i', '/\bhi\b/i', '/\byo\b/i', '/\bsup\b/i');
```

or a single pattern, i.e by **OR**:

```
'/\b('.join('|', $hello).')\b/i'
```

What you currently pass, is a string like this:

```
'/\bArray\b/i'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = "Would you like to say hi to him?";
$hello = array('hello', 'hi', 'yo', 'sup');
$pattern = "";
foreach ($hello as $h)
{
    if ($pattern != "") $pattern = $pattern . "|";
    $pattern = $pattern . preg_quote ($h);
}
$words = preg_replace ('/\b(' . $pattern . ')\b/i', 'Bonjour', $words);
```